# Appium: App crashes continously when appium inspector is launched

Tags: ios, iphone, appium, appium-ios

After launching the Appium server, when I click on inspector icon in appium, it opens the Simulator and then my app page appear and then shuts down automatically. Everytime I click on Inspector icon, the iphone simulator loads up > shows the glimpse of the app screen and then navigates back to home screen of the device.

I tried with 2-3 different test apps which I downloaded and they worked fine and Appium inspector was working fine with them.

Comment: use UIAutomater instead of appium inspector.

Comment: @Gaurav: I am using appium on mac for automation of an iOS app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use android 'uiautomatorviewer' which acts same as the Appium Inspector. "uiautomatorviewer" is a GUI tool using which you can view the UI components of any android application.

To access uiautomatorviewer:

- Go to the directory where android-sdk is installed.
- Under android-sdk -> tools -> click on uiautomatorviewer.

You will find a green icon for 'device screenshot' which will take a snapshot of the current active screen of your device:

[image]